# API для игровой статистики из CS:GO

Tags: api, бот, discord

делаю дискорд бота по CS:GO, и мне надо получать статистику игрока по его SteamID.

В частности интересует как получить текущий XP.
Но во всех API, которые я нашел, требуется API-Ключ от Стима, но у меня сервис без авторизации.

Я думал, что Стим/кс не дают такой возможности, но однако я смог найти ботов, которые показывают статистику, в целом я хочу полностью их скопировать, но для своих личных целей, ниже приложил пример.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где можно найти нужное мне API?

Comment: Так они, наверное, используют API ключ )